# How to check for cookies in a template tag

Tags: python, django

I tried this:

```
{% if request.COOKIE['register'] %}
...
{% endif %}
```

But I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '['register']' from 'request.COOKIE['register']'
```

How can I check for a cookie from a template?

Comment: Try `request.COOKIE.register`. Dictionary values are accessed via dot-notation in Django templates.

Comment: @Dave It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use bracket syntax in a Django template. Instead use dot syntax:

```
{% if request.COOKIE.register %}
...
{% endif %}
```